"RuntimeError: Failed raising error" when using mysql connector python in virtual enviroments, but not in global
When trying to connect a DB in python, using mysql-connector-python, like this:
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user='root',
    password='root',
    database='botstream'
)

I got this problem, and just cant't connect to database or handle the exception, as it can't be raised. However, when I use global enviroment, this problem does not occur anymore.
I've tried resetting the virtual environment (venv) and reinstalling the dependency, but it hasn't resolved the issue.
I expected the connection to be established successfully, allowing me to interact with the database. Additionally, if any issues occurred during the connection attempt, I expected to be able to handle the exception properly. However, this was not the case, as the exception could not be raised. Interestingly, when using the global environment, this problem did not occur.

please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, additionally, supply versions of all major components being used.
